# conversion of the nvarchar value overflowed an int column for inserting from file

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I'm trying to insert data into a specific table from a txt file, having an BPC xml schema for it. The txt file contains lots of rows and for some reason it's giving me an error when reaches to value '2999999999' for one fied. I've tried with Cast as Int, but still nothing.

This is the SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO regioneanhotelidmapping(RegionID, EANHotelID)
    SELECT cast(RegionID as int), cast(EANHotelID as int)

     FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\EAN\RegionEANHotelIDMapping\RegionEANHotelIDMapping.txt',
                             FORMATFILE='D:\EAN\eanRefresh\bcpxml\RegionEANHotelIDMapping.xml', FIRSTROW = 2) as BCP
```

And this is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="01" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="|" MAX_LENGTH="2000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="02" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n" MAX_LENGTH="2000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>

 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="01" NAME="RegionID"       xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NULLABLE="YES"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="02" NAME="EANHotelID"     xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" NULLABLE="YES"/>


  </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

And error is: Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The conversion of the nvarchar value '2999999999' overflowed an int column.

Comment: 2,147,483,647 is the maximum value for a sql int column. Thus you've overflowed it with 2,999,999,999. If you need to insert a value higher than 2,147,483,647 you will need to make that column bigint.

Comment: Hi @JacobH ! Thanks for the answer. So, should I change the column type for that or I just truncate the records from the txt? Issues is that, this is a mapping table and I need all the results...

Comment: Yes, just change your column type to bigint if you need an integer that size.

Comment: Thanks! Worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That number is too large for an INT, you'll need to modify the data type to be BIGINT for that value. The limit is 2.3B and change, where you're at 2.9B and change.
Please see the following page for reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql